# Filling array from file won't work

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io

I have made a 'Map' array and I am attempting to populate it from a 'map' file. On creation I assign the value '0' to each element of the array but the 'Map' file contains the following:

MAP:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I load the map using 'loadMap()'

loadMap():

```
void room::loadMap()
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    string line;
    ifstream mapFile(NAME + "_MAP.txt");

    while(!mapFile.eof())
    {
        for(int i=0; i<cellsY; i++)
        {
            getline(mapFile,line,'\n');

            for(int j=0; j<cellsX; j++)
            {
                getline(mapFile,line,' ');
                map[(cellsX*j) + cellsY] = atoi(line.c_str());
            };
        };
    }

    y = 10;
    x = 15;
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        {
            cout << endl;
            for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
            {
                cout << map[(x*j) + y];
            };
        };
}
```

In this example the elements are still assigned to '0', but I am trying to mimic the Map files layout.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "reading file eof".

Comment: Why are you using `getline`?  This looks like a good case for using `file >> variable`.

Comment: Is your file actually opening successfully?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The `getline` in the outer loop is justified, if he wants to be sure that each row is on a separate line.  Not using the line he read in the outer loop is less good.  And using `getline`, followed by `atoi`, as he's doing, isn't a very good idea either.  (Not to mention that `getline( mapFile, line, ' ' )` will read until the next space, and will _not_ stop on a newline.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you never test that any of the input works, nor
that the open succeeded.   Then, in the outer loop, you read
a line from the file, and throw it away, before reading further
in the inner loop.  And your calcule of the index is wrong.

What you're probably looking for is something like:

```
std::ifstream mapFile(...);
if ( !mapFile.is_open() ) {
    //  Error handling...
}
for ( int i = 0; mapFile && i != cellsY; ++ i ) {
    std::string line;
    if ( std::getline( mapFile, line ) ) {
        std::istringstream text( line );
        for ( int j = 0; j != cellsX && text >> map[cells X * i + j]; ++ j ) {
        }
        if ( j != cellsX ) {
            //  Error: missing elements in line
        }
        text >> std::ws;
        if ( text && text.get() != EOF ) {
            //  Error: garbage at end of line
        }
    }
}
```

For the error handling, the simplest is just to output an
appropriate error message and continue, noting the error so you
can return some sort of error code at the end.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use `mapFile >> value` instead of `getline` and `istringstream`?

Comment: Because the input format requires (or seems to require) one line per row; `mapFile >> value` will accept any sequence of `cellsX * cellsY` values.  If that's OK, of course, dropping the `getline` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I will drop the getline I believe.. still working out the kinks atm

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The major problem was the index issue. I had just learned about mimic arrays, thank you for the help. I have removed a few things and I use the mapFile >> value method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
void room::loadMap()
{
   int x=0;
   int y=0;
   ifstream mapFile(NAME + "_MAP.txt");

   for(int i=0; i<cellsY; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j<cellsX; j++)
      {
         int v;
         mapFile >> v;
         if ( mapFile.eof() )
         {
            break;
         }
         map[(cellsX*j) + cellsY] = v;
      }
   }

   y = 10;
   x = 15;
   for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
   {
      cout << endl;
      for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
      {
         cout << map[(x*j) + y];
      };
   };
}
```

Comment: The `while (!mapFile.eof())` is certainly wrong.  (Where do people get such ideas?)

Comment: The `if ( mapFile.eof() )` is still wrong.  (As is simply using a `break` here.)